# Multibyte safe string cropping to a given byte length

Tags: php, utf, multibyte

I have a string which might contain multibyte characters. That string has a maximum byte length constraint. How can I implement that constraint without splitting a multibyte character?

E.g. limit "x" to maximum 7 bytes ("" is 4 bytes). The correct result would be "x", which is 5 bytes.

A trivial `substr("x", 0, 7)` would break the string. Also a trivial `mb_substr("x", 0, 7)` would return "x" which is 9 bytes.

Comment: You should still answer and accept your own solution, even if nobody is posting one. Leaving it open unanswered doesn't help anyone. Of course it's a good idea to keep it open for some time ('till tomorrow maybe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mb_strcut() is the equivalent to mb_substr() but at the byte level.

Doesn't it solve your problem?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strcut.php